# Use UIButton to navigate between UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uistoryboardsegue

I have programmatically constructed a `UIButton` in `view1` which is currently displayed. The goal is when the button is clicked, `view1` will switch to `view2`. I know how to achieve this by using `segue`, but since I can't control-drag the `UIButton` into my `.m` file, how do I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Add a target to your button

```
[myButton addTarget:self 
             action:@selector(myAction) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and then segue

```
- (void)myAction {
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:"identifier" sender:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then implement a method in that view controller like so: (assign an identifier to the segue in the storyboard)

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueName" sender:nil];
}
```

or using the identifier of a view controller in the storyboard

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```